# $windows.localStorage reset when I call setItem() after I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

[image: The output]The following is my `AddToCart` factory:

```
.factory('AddToCart', function ($window) {
var products = {};
products.list = [];

return {
    addProduct: function (_sku, _image, _name, _price, _quantity, _remark) {
        return products.list.push({
            id: products.list.length,
            sku: _sku,
            image: _image,
            name: _name,
            price: _price,
            quantity: _quantity,
            remark: _remark
        });
    },
    updateProduct: function (_id, _sku, _image, _name, _price, _quantity, _remark, _show) {
        return products.list[_id] = {
            id: _id,
            sku: _sku,
            image: _image,
            name: _name,
            price: _price,
            quantity: _quantity,
            remark: _remark,
            show: _show
        };
    }, 
    saveProduct: function () { 
        $window.localStorage.setItem("CartProducts", JSON.stringify(products.list));            
    },       
    getLocalStorageProduct: function () {
        return JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem("CartProducts"));
    }        
}
});
```

I call them this:

```
AddToCart.addProduct(....); //save in list
AddToCart.saveProduct(); //save to local storage
```

Then I output the saved items:

```
AddToCart.getLocalStorageProduct(); //output the list items
```

OK, It works perfect so far

**The problem is** when I reload the page and call the `AddProduct()` and `SaveProduct()`, the local storage just reset the data stored before and start with storing the item from `id1`. How can I storing the data without resetting the data before??? Any idea to solve or other method to replace the local storage?

Comment: Where in your code you load the data from the localStorage? There function `getLocalStorageProduct` is never used.

Comment: sorry my mistake here, but i still doesnt  get what i want

Comment: are you trying to save an array in the localstorage ?

Comment: I still don't understand where/when this function is being called. You need to set the initial value of the CartProducts when you first load the page (which is exactly the same on refresh).

Comment: yes, the output u may see the capture i just uploaded above

Comment: **I add the Product List by calling this way**

Comment: `AddToCart.addProduct(_this.object.sku, _this.object.image, _this.object.product_name);`

Comment: `AddToCart.saveProduct(); //save to local storage`

Comment: `DisplayPopUp.showAlert("Order", "Add to cart successfully");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot attached by you, you are trying to save the products in the local storage with Key CartProducts. I am not 100% sure but the issue is that you are overriding the current value of CartProducts every time with out checking that if there is already an item in it. In the save function you should first check if there is any item present with the key CartProducts and if its there than you should fetch the current array, convert to JSON and push the new object in the array. Now you should save it.

Try with code like this for saving product.

```
saveProduct: function () { 
            var cartProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("CartProducts"));
        if(cartProducts == null)
        {
            console.log("CartProducts == null");
            $window.localStorage.setItem("CartProducts", JSON.stringify(products.list)); 
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("CartProducts != null");
            for(var i = 0; i < cartProducts.length; i++)
            {
                products.list.push(cartProducts[i]);
            }

            $window.localStorage.setItem("CartProducts", JSON.stringify(products.list)); 
        }
        //$window.localStorage.setItem("CartProducts", JSON.stringify(products.list));            
    },
```

Comment: I have ever think about that too, but I am not sure about the codind to check. Would you give me some tips?

Answer (score 0):

you should get the `localstorage` value first and add that to `products.list` before doing any operation in ths factorythen you should push what ever the new product entries are to `products.list`. by this you can preserve localstorage value.

```
getLocalstore:function()
{
    if($window.localStorage.getItem("CartProducts"))
    {
                    this.products.list=JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem("CartProducts"));
    }
else
{
 this.products.list=[];
}
}
```

add the method in `AddToCart` factory.and call this method prior to any other methods in this factory in what ever controller you are using.

Comment: hmm... Im afraid this is not what I want. But thx for your effort anyway!!!